# Document mode defaults to 8, though using IE11. Why?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, http-headers, compatibility

I have a problem that my webpage does not display as i wish it to do.

When opening the F12 developers tool in IE11 it says "Document mode: 8 (Default)".

If i change it to mode 9 or higher the page displays as i want it to do.

My code is included in the host web page through an Iframe. I do unfortunatly not have access to edit the host code. The host code includes the code:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
```

I thought this code would ensure that the code was not shown in document 8? The code is included at the end of the head tag, with 88 lines of code in front of it. Could this be what is causing it to use document mode 8? How can i work around this when i am not able to edit the head code?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. There must not be anything which could affect document mode before the `meta x-ua`. Any `style` or `script` (also linked ones) tag before the `x-ua` will set the document mode, and the `x-ua` is ignored. Actually you can see a warning about this in the console. And don't forget to use proper HTML5 DTD, that's the best way to set document mode correctly.

Comment: I shall have to try to get the web editors to change it. Would make my day if it did work, as it looks so much better.. Thank yoU!